# How can I change the behavior of a key in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, key-bindings

I want to change the behavior of the key `TAB`. I don't know if it's possible: I want to force `TAB` to do what `M-i` does.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want to remap the command that is bound to `M-i` to `TAB`.

If you want to do that in the `global-map` then this does it:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "TAB") (kbd "M-i"))
```

If you want to do it in a particular keymap, say `foo-map`, then this does it:

```
(define-key foo-map (kbd "TAB") (kbd "M-i"))
```

---

But typically users want to *remap a command's keys to another command*.  For that you use `[remap OLD-COMMAND]` as the first arg to `global-set-key` or the second arg to `define-key`, and you use the `NEW-COMMAND` as the last arg.

Alternatively, for that you can use function `substitute-key-definition`, which also lets you change keymaps.  `C-h f substitute-key-definition` starts with this:

> `substitute-key-definition` is a compiled Lisp function in `subr.el`.
>
> `(substitute-key-definition OLDDEF NEWDEF KEYMAP &optional OLDMAP)`
>
> Replace `OLDDEF` with `NEWDEF` for any keys in `KEYMAP` now defined as `OLDDEF`.
>
> In other words, `OLDDEF` is replaced with `NEWDEF` wherever it appears.
>   Alternatively, if optional fourth argument `OLDMAP` is specified, we redefine
>   in `KEYMAP` as `NEWDEF` those keys which are defined as `OLDDEF` in `OLDMAP`.